# nextFocusForward doesn't go to the end of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:nextFocusForward="@id/et_two"/> 

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:nextFocusForward="@id/et_next"/>
```

The focus goes to the et_two. But the cursor is on the left. I'd like the cursor to go to the end so that I can use backspace or contiguously type.

For example,
I tried with nextFocusLeft/Right & nextFocusDown/up. All of them didn't work. But went to weird fields.

I have multiple edit text and I want the users edit them easier.

EDITED:

Let's say () is EditText and | is a cursor. and I type (John|) enter then I want the cursor goes to the next EditText but already filled (01011112222). At the moment the cursor goes to the beginning of the next EditText like (|01011112222). But I want it to go to the end like (01011112222|) so that I can delete with 'backspace' from the back and then I can naturally edit the phone number.

Comment: Can you please explain "I can use backspace or contiguously type" ? Do you want the edittext to type in reverse? Also, what will the language likely be?

Comment: For example, Let's say () is EditText and | is a cursor. and I type (John|) enter then I want the cursor goes to the next EditText but already filled (01011112222). At the moment the cursor goes to the beginning of the next EditText like (|01011112222). But I want it to go to the end like (01011112222|) so that I can delete with 'backspace' from the back and then I can naturally edit the phone number. @10101010